# Akka HTTP Java: not override abstract method yeOldeTestNames() in org.scalatest.Suite

Tags: sbt, junit4, scalatest, akka-http, akka-testkit

I am going to use `akka-http` with `Java`. The routing done successfully and run. But when i trying to write test case using `JUnitRouteTest`, i got an error.

```
com.james.controllers.PingPongApiTest is not abstract and does not override abstract method yeOldeTestNames() in org.scalatest.Suite
```

I am following [akka http route testkit documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.8/java/http/routing-dsl/testkit.html#Supporting_Custom_Test_Frameworks). According to this documentation, we required only `akka-http-testkit`. But for `Java` We also required `Junit` depedency. With only junit dependency i got another error is `cannot access org.scalatest.junit.JUnitSuiteLike`. I am also inject scala test depedency as below:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-http-experimental_2.11" % "2.4.8",
 "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-http-testkit_2.11" % "2.4.8" % "test",
 "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test",
 "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "3.0.0" % "test"
)
```

Then i got the below error:

```
com.james.controllers.PingPongApiTest is not abstract and does not override abstract method yeOldeTestNames() in org.scalatest.Suite
[error] public class PingPongApiTest extends JUnitRouteTest {
[error]     TestRoute route = testRoute(new PingPongApi().handleGetPingRequest());
[error] 
[error]     @Test
[error]     public void testGetPingRequest() {
[error] 
[error]         route.run(HttpRequest.GET("/ping"))
[error]                 .assertStatusCode(StatusCodes.OK)
[error]                 .assertEntity("pong");
[error]     }
[error] }
[error] (test:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 10 Aug, 2016 11:28:11 AM
```

How could i resolve the problem. Following is my code:

**Route Class**

```
public class PingPongApi  {

 public Route handleGetPingRequest() {
    return get(() -> route(
            path("ping", () -> complete("pong"))
    ));
 } 
}
```

**Test Class**

```
public class PingPongApiTest extends JUnitRouteTest {
 TestRoute route = testRoute(new PingPongApi().handleGetPingRequest());

 @Test
 public void testGetPingRequest() {

    route.run(HttpRequest.GET("/ping"))
            .assertStatusCode(StatusCodes.OK)
            .assertEntity("pong");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for above problem. The main problem with our dependencies versions. For running Java Routing test cases, we required `scalatest` dependency, because `JUnitRouteTest` using `scalatest`. Following are the dependencies we required.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-http-experimental_2.11" % "2.4.8",
 "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-http-testkit_2.11" % "2.4.8" % "test",
 "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test",
 "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test",
 "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test" exclude("junit", "junit")
)
```

Comment: Thanks Harmeet ! this solved my problem. For akka 2.4.10 and maven you need: <dependency>
     <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>